# VM filesystem in read-only mode

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, lvm, virtualbox, read-only

I have a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM with a virtual disk that is mounting as a read-only filesystem. I'm not sure why that is, and my attempts to remount as read/write haven't worked.

One of the last things I did before it went read-only was to extend the size of the disk. What I did was:

- used `VBoxManage modifymedium —resize` (from the Mac host system) to extend the VM disk image,
- booted the guest system off a GParted ISO and used that to join the new space into my existing main partition,
- booted into the guest system normally, then
- ran `lvresize` and `resize2fs` to extend the filesystem into the new space.

This was the second time I had done this, actually, and seemed to be working fine. I ran a process on the machine that filled up a lot of the space. That was the last successful thing I remember doing before running into this read-only mode issue.

I don't see anything in dmesg that looks to me to be about filesystem issues or causes for going into read-only mode. I see this:

```
[    1.809918] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.230023] Adding 524284k swap on /dev/mapper/trails-swap_1.  Priority:-1     extents:1 across:524284k
[    2.242615] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

/proc/cmdline shows that same command.

I've tried different combinations parameters to the mount command, like:

`$ sudo mount -o remount,rw`

`$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mapper/trails-root`

`$ sudo mount -o remount,rw -t ext3 /dev/sda5 /`

Not sure what I should be looking for, but I get no output from these.

Booting into recovery mode and doing an fsck runs without issue.

If I go into GRUB options on boot and remove the "ro" I still end up in read-only mode.

fdisk says my two LVM volumes on the resized parition don't contain valid partition tables.

Here's the output of some commands that might be helpful:

**`$ sudo more /etc/fstab`**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/trails-root       /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/trails-swap_1       none            swap    sw              0       0
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
```

**`$ fdisk -l`**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 59.1 GB, 59055800320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7179 cylinders, total 115343360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005deaa

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   115343359    57420801    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   115343359    57420800   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/trails-root: 58.3 GB, 58258882560 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7082 cylinders, total 113786880 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/trails-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/trails-swap_1: 536 MB, 536870912 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65 cylinders, total 1048576 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/trails-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

**`$ sudo pvdisplay`**

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda5
VG Name               trails
PV Size               54.76 GiB / not usable 2.81 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              14018
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          14018
PV UUID               ew9UUW-fJbf-I4o1-otM3-Rpeg-nyK6-0Hn0ol

/etc/lvm/cache/.cache.tmp: fopen failed: No space left on device
```

**`$ sudo vgdisplay`**

```
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               trails
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  9
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               54.76 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              14018
Alloc PE / Size       14018 / 54.76 GiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
VG UUID               wZqfAM-DgIg-Z1P1-TSqi-iycL-O2pL-s2x8fU

Couldn't create temporary archive name.
Volume group "trails" metadata archive failed.
Couldn't create temporary archive name.
Volume group "trails" metadata archive failed.
Couldn't create temporary text file name.
Backup of volume group trails metadata failed.
/etc/lvm/cache/.cache.tmp: fopen failed: No space left on device
```

**`$ sudo lvm`**

```
lvm> lvs
  LV     VG     Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root   trails -wi-ao  54.26g
  swap_1 trails -wi-ao 512.00m
```

**`$ sudo lvdisplay`**

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Name                /dev/trails/root
VG Name                trails
LV UUID                cfACOE-8PCl-jZye-dIZW-KOaS-dnOD-RwO8Ek
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                54.26 GiB
Current LE             13890
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Name                /dev/trails/swap_1
VG Name                trails
LV UUID                EqcxJH-jOdB-NLIW-fDNi-vWn4-nWbe-feFRM6
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                512.00 MiB
Current LE             128
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:1

/etc/lvm/cache/.cache.tmp: fopen failed: No space left on device
```

Enough? (Too much?)

I'm not sure where to go from here. Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I had hit the inode limit.

**`$ tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/trails-root | grep -i inode`**

```
...
Inode count:     3549600
Free inodes:     0
...
```